# How to find the $n$ zeros of $\displaystyle1+z^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How to find the $n$ zeros of $1+z^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $z^n + 1 =0$, we get $z^n = -1 \implies z^n = e^{i (2k+1)\pi}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence, the roots are $e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The distinct roots are obtained as $e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n}$, where $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Wow! Two almost identical answers! I'm deleting mine and upvoting this answer. +1

Comment: That actually was the roots I found, but according to the correction, I am supposed to find $z_k = e^{\frac{i(2k+1)\pi}{3}}$, $k = 0,...,n-1$. So should I assume there is a mistake in the correction ?

Answer (score 1):

Write $z^n=-1$ and look at it geometrically: $z=e^{i \alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$ zeros of $Re^{i\theta}$ are

$$z_k=\sqrt[n]R \exp\left({\frac{2ik\pi+\theta}{n}}\right),\quad k=0,\ldots,n-1$$